# How to switch between multiple variables using an if-else statement in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean

How would I make a switch between multiple variables using a single switch variable?

**Update:**
To clarify the intent is to switch back between these two sets of variables an indefinite amount of times.

When I try this I get the following error.

```
a1= 'process1'
a2 = 'process2'

b1 = 'action1'
b2 = 'action2'

switch = True # the switch to indicate which set of variables to use
N = 10        # the number of times to switch between the two sets of variables

# alternate between two sets of variables N times
for i in range (N):
    active_process, active_action = a1, b1 if switch else a2, b2

    print("active_process: %s, active_action is: %s" %(active_process, active_action))
    switch = not switch
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/username/.PyCharm2019.3/config/scratches/scratch_10.py", line 10, in <module>
    active_process, active_action = a1, b1 if switch else a2, b2
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: You don't need `i` or `switch` here: `for response, greeting in (a1, b1), (a2, b2):`.

Comment: Or perhaps more idiomatic: `responses = ['yes', 'no']; greetings = ['hello', 'goodby']; for response, greeting in zip(responses, greetings):`

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I updated to make more clear the intent of the question.  There was a switch between the two sets of variables an indefinite amount of time.

Comment: I'd write *that* as `for ap, aa in islice(cycle([(a1,b1), (a2,b2)]), N):` (where `islice` and `cycle` are imported from `itertools`). Or if you need/want `i`, `for i, (ap, aa) in zip(range(N), cycle(...))`.

Comment: The error comes from precedence issues: `(a1, b1) if switch else (a2, b2)`.

Comment: I guess my point is, I try to avoid variables whose only purpose is flow control. :)

Comment: Awesome, I haven't used itertools in-depth but this will give me an excuse to learn them.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You're making this far too fragile.  You have a table of greeting/response values and a Boolean that tell you which to use.  Just do this with a direct-access list:

```
table = [ ("process1", "action1"),
          ("process2" , "action2")
        ]

N = 10
for i in range(10):
    print("%s, the answer is: %s" % table[i %2])
```

Alternately, use a dict:

```
table = { True:  ("process1", "action1"),
          False: ("process2" , "action2")
        }
N = 10
for i in range(N):
    print("%s, the answer is: %s" % table[i %2])
```

Comment: The intent was to switch between the two sets of variables an indefinite amount of times.  This is easily accomplished if you take the modulo i%2 to reference the index of the table list.

Comment: Yes, it is.  I answered the posted question; you updated afterward.

Comment: The only change was to update the variables so that they were not quite as misleading as to what the original intent of the question was and to change the number of times to alternate from 2 to 10.  Do you mind if I update your answer with the i%2 as the index of table?

Comment: Thank you @Prune I don't want to seem that I'm not appreciative of you.  You're right a table is more robust!

Answer (score 0):

Using a list to pack and unpack the items gave the desired outcome:

```
a1= 'process1'
a2 = 'process2'

b1 = 'action1'
b2 = 'action2'

switch = True # the switch to indicate which set of variables to use
N = 10        # the number of times to switch between the two sets of 

# alternate between two sets of variables N times
for i in range (N):
    [active_process, active_action] = [a1, b1] if switch else [a2, b2]

    print("active_process: %s, active_action is: %s" %(active_process, active_action))
    switch = not switch
```

Output:

```
active_process: process1, active_action is: action1
active_process: process2, active_action is: action2
active_process: process1, active_action is: action1
active_process: process2, active_action is: action2
active_process: process1, active_action is: action1
active_process: process2, active_action is: action2
active_process: process1, active_action is: action1
active_process: process2, active_action is: action2
active_process: process1, active_action is: action1
active_process: process2, active_action is: action2

Process finished with exit code 0
```